# Load Gravatars only once in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, images, gravatar

It looks like a user's gravatar is loaded in chat every time he adds a chat message, although it's already loaded before.

I think it's sufficient to load that image only once, and use the same loaded resource when the user adds a chat message.

It might not look so important, but *does* matter for [people who have problems with Gravatar](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/546/make-gravatar-images-be-requested-using-https).

So to clarify my suggestion: I suggest to make the gravatar image for every user in the chat load only once at the first time it's needed, and then be used whenever he makes an action (mainly add a new message).

Comment: @PopularDemand: You mean loading every time? I'm sure it's what happens, if your internet connection has problems with gravatar you will realize that it loads everytime.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying now. Yeah, this makes sense.

Comment: Very interesting. I've always noticed the problem, but wasn't sure how to implement a solution (can the same image node be used over and over?) And even if it does, won't it have to load it again?

Comment: AFAIK once a resource is loaded it can be used again and again in any place on the page. A quick solution I could think of is to make a UserID<->ImageURL hash and look it up whenever a new chat message is posted.